# SAML / is RelayState required for signed logout request?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I wish to confirm that RelayState is required for a valid signed SAML logout request.

We have federated Microsoft's ADFS 2012 R2 with Oracle's Identity Federation where ADFS is the SP and OIF is the IdP. As a basis, we followed [Integrating ADFS 2.0/3.0 SP with OIF IdP](https://blogs.oracle.com/dcarru/entry/integrating_adfs_2_0_sp).

Everything works, except logout. We have another SP doing a logout and working with OIF. One difference we've found is that ADFS is not sending a RelayState parameter with its signed logout request, but the other SP is. I've been using [SAMLTool's Validate Logout Req](https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php), where I input the following:

- SAML Logout Request
- EntityId of the source
- Target URL, Destination of the Logout Request
- SigAlg
- Signature of the SAML Logout Request
- X.509 cert of the source (to check Signature)
- Ignore timing issues: checked

That then gives me the error:

```
In order to check Signature you must provide the RelayState parameter and the X.509 cert
```

If I input RelayState along with my other values in [SAMLTool's Validate Logout Req](https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php) then it reports back that my signed logout request is valid.

In the case of ADFS, because it does not have a RelayState parameter, I cannnot get [SAMLTool's Validate Logout Req](https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php) to say that a logout from ADFS is valid.

All that said, I cannot find anywhere in the SAML spec that says RelayState is required for a signed logout request. Can anyone confirm that it is required and back it up with documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LogoutRequest` message would not have a reference to the `RelayState` parameter (as the other post suggests) but it is part of the so-called binding that is used to convey messages between SAML parties. Assuming that the Logout uses the `HTTP-Redirect`, `HTTP-POST` or `Artifact` binding, the spec **allows** for the sender to include a `RelayState` parameter and the receiver must then return that same `RelayState` parameter as a part of the response (as a way for the sender to keep state).

See section 3.4.3 RelayState of the SAML bindings document: https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf for the HTTP-Redirect binding:

> **3.4.3 RelayState**
>
> RelayState data MAY be included with a SAML protocol message transmitted with
> this binding. The value MUST NOT exceed 80
> bytes in length and SHOULD be integrity protected by the entity
> creating the message independent of any other protections that may or
> may not exist during message transmission. Signing is not realistic
> given the space limitation, but because the value is exposed to
> third-party tampering, the entity SHOULD ensure that the value has not
> been tampered with by using a checksum, a pseudo-random value, or
> similar means. If a SAML request message is accompanied by RelayState
> data, then the SAML responder MUST return its SAML protocol response
> using a binding that also supports a RelayState mechanism, and it MUST
> place the exact data it received with the request into the
> corresponding RelayState parameter in the response. If no such value
> is included with a SAML request message, or if the SAML response
> message is being generated without a corresponding request, then the
> SAML responder MAY include RelayState data to be interpreted by the
> recipient based on the use of a profile or prior agreement between the
> parties

For the other bindings a similar section exists. So as @nzpcmad says: it's not mandatory to include it in a request.

Comment: In other words, it's not mandatory. The tool is incorrect in requiring it. ADFS e.g. does not supply it for SP Initiated.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this as the answer and open a ticket with Oracle and see what they say. If something interesting results, I'll try to come back here with a status update.

Comment: We ultimately solved our problem and sign out between ADFS and OAM is now working. The main issue was outdated ADFS metadata in OAM.

Answer (score 0):

Reading SAMLv2 core spec "Single Logout Protocol" XML schema for the SAML LogoutRequestType

```xml
<element name="LogoutRequest" type="samlp:LogoutRequestType" />
<complexType name="LogoutRequestType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="samlp:RequestAbstractType">
            <sequence>
                <choice>
                    <element ref="saml:BaseID" />
                    <element ref="saml:NameID" />
                    <element ref="saml:EncryptedID" />
                </choice>
                <element ref="samlp:SessionIndex" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="Reason" type="string" use="optional" />
            <attribute name="NotOnOrAfter" type="dateTime" use="optional" />
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="SessionIndex" type="string" />
```

does not mention the RelayState Element. The "Single Logout Profile" in the SAMLv2 profile spec does also not mention RelayState.

I would say this suggests that RelayState (which is a request parameter, so can only be used in a front-channel binding) is not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. Based on what you said, why would RelayState be mandatory given that the spec does not list it? Or is your last sentence a typo?

Comment: RelayState is defined in the SAML Binding specification, not in the core SAML spec. Not surprising you found nothing (See @Hans Z. response)

Comment: Even there the parameter is optional